# Would a semicolon be appropriate here?

Tags: sentence, semicolons

I'm talking about a book here and here's the sentence after

> The significance of constantly challenging the perceived wisdom is emphasised; urging us to pry into the smallest details no matter how insignificant they may seem, and draw conclusions from the data collected.

I'd appreciate any help

Comment: What follows the semicolon should form an independent clause (maybe what you mean by "the sentence after"). However, the closest thing we have to a main verb after the semicolon has no subject. Who or what is "urging us"?

Comment: As written it should be a comma. If you use a semicolon, you need a subject as @TaliesinMerlin said, e.g. "this is urging us...."

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Oh okay tahnku so "My prior knowledge of this sector was limited; therefore, I was surprised to learn about ...." would work? Or would I have to take away therefore to make it an independent clause?